# Stumped by JQuery $.each behavior

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a php file which when called returns a simple non associative array of string values. When I request the array using the jQuery get routine I get the array I expect, but when I try to iterate it , instead of getting the two string values, the $.each command iterates every char. I don't understand what I'm getting wrong.

My code:

```
<div name ="test_spot" id ="test_spot" width="200" height="400">Test</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

function getOutput(){

    $.get( "data.php", function( data ) {

        // This call verifies the the array is what I would expect.
        // ["one","two"]. Then I comment this out and run the code below.
        //$( "#test_spot" ).html( data);

        $.each(data,  function(index, value){

            // This outputs each char instead of each string each on its own line in the div.
            // [
            // "
            // o
            // n
            // e etc
            $('#test_spot').append($('<p>').text(value)); 

        });

    });
}

</script>

<button onClick="getOutput()" style="height: 60px; width:100px;" >Test</button>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you show the output of `console.log(data)`

Comment: did you actually look at the data in a debugger?

Comment: the console.log(data) looked like the description above ; [ "one" , "two"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expecting an object but are getting back a JSON string. When you pass that to `.each` it iterates over the characters in the string.

Try specifying the `dataType` as `json` like this:

```
$.get( "data.php", function( data ) { 
        $.each(data,  function(index, value){ 
             $('#test_spot').append($('<p>').text(value)); 
        });

}, "json" );
```

Or, like charlietfl points out, simply use

```
$.getJSON( "data. php", function( data ) {
        $.each(data,  function(index, value){ 
             $('#test_spot').append($('<p>').text(value)); 
        });
});
```

If that still doesnt work, Id look at the output and make sure that it is valid JSON.

Comment: is actually `dataType` argument...but even simpler is `$.getJSON()` which does it internally

Comment: Thank you. I just pasted your code in place (fixing the space in the data.php fliename). The first one was a no go but the second one worked. It was deceiving to me . I thought I was looking at the contents of the array but it must have just been a string formed like the contents of the array. Should I have not used "json_encode($arr)" in my php return code?

Comment: No,`json_encode($arr)` is the correct way to send the data back. But you need to understand that `JSON` *is a string representation of an object*. Its expected to be a string. When you retrieve it, you have to convert the string into an object using whatever methods your language of choice (javascript in this case) offers to do so. Some methods like `getJSON` automatically handle the conversion in the background, other methods like `get` will try to guess (and sometimes get it wrong and need to be told to convert it)  https://www.copterlabs.com/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/